# How to query a row from a table with 2 primary keys in Flask SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, flask-sqlalchemy

My goal is to save a row from a table (with two primary keys) into a variable using Flask SQLAlchemy then delete that row/variable from the database. This table connects two other tables in a many to many relationship. The data scheme is below:

[image]

In my model, many users can sign up for many yoga classes. From what I understand if I wanted a user to cancel their registration for a class, I would need to just delete the appropriate signups row right? I understand how to query an item with one primary key `signup = Signups.query.get_or_404(primary_key)`, then delete
`db.session.delete(signup)  db.session.commit()`
but how do you do this with two primary keys? (I would prefer to do it this way rather than creating an id for each signup).

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time

from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

bcrypt = Bcrypt()
db = SQLAlchemy()



class Signups(db.Model):
    """Table created to produce the many-to-many relationship between the tables 'users' and 'classes'"""

    __tablename__ = 'signups'

    user_id = db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    class_id = db.Column('class_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('classes.id'), primary_key=True)

class User(db.Model):
    """User in the system."""

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True,)
    password = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False, unique=True,)
    email = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, unique=True,)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False,)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False,)
    image_url = db.Column(db.Text, default="/static/images/profile_pic.png",)

    classes = db.relationship('Classes', secondary='signups', backref='users')

   
    @classmethod
    def authenticate(cls, email, password):
        """Find user with `email` and `password`.
        If can't find matching user (or if password is wrong), returns False.
        """

        user = cls.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

        if user:
            is_auth = bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password)
            if is_auth:
                return user

        return False



class Instructor(db.Model):
    
    __tablename__ = 'instructors'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True,)
    password = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False,)
    email = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False, unique=True,)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False,)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False,)
    image_url = db.Column(db.Text, default="/static/images/profile_pic.png",)

    classes = db.relationship('Classes', backref='instructor')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Instructor {}>'.format(self.first_name)



    @classmethod
    def authenticate(cls, email, password):
        """Find user with `email` and `password`.
        If can't find matching user (or if password is wrong), returns False.
        """

        instructor = cls.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

        if instructor:
            is_auth = bcrypt.check_password_hash(instructor.password, password)
            if is_auth:
                return instructor

        return False

class Classes(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'classes'

    id = db.Column( db.Integer, primary_key=True,)
    class_instructor = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('instructors.id', ondelete="cascade"),)
    location = db.Column(db.String,)
    start_date_time = db.Column(db.DateTime,)
    end_date_time = db.Column(db.DateTime,)
    class_users = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete="cascade"),)

    def serialize(self):
        """Serialize classes SQLAlchemy obj to dictionary."""
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "class_instructor": self.instructor.first_name,
            "location": self.location,
            "start_date_time": self.start_date_time,
            "end_date_time": self.end_date_time,
        }


def connect_db(app):
    """Connect this database to provided Flask app.

    You should call this in your Flask app.
    """

    db.app = app
    db.init_app(app)
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your models?

Comment: Just added them now

Comment: You could use joins but you can try this as well https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many